# Pycharm interface change when i plot something

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am new ussing pycharm, first time.

I had a problem with Linux and i had to restore the PATH and restore the pycharm configuration. But when I plot something after restore the problem, doesn't see the same interface. Before the problem when I plot a image shows three buttons home, a glass, and the arrows but now the interface is different. And the other interface its the normal when you plot something always have that buttons.

There is a solution for change that? I read something that pycharm choose between scikit or matplotlib but didn't find the option to change that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check **Settings | Tools | Python Plots**, toggle "Use interactive mode" and che